# Double Fourier Series coefficient derivation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We are looking at the rectangular membrane problem.

We're assuming that $f(x,y)$ is a smooth function defined on the rectangle $\{(x,y) : 0 \leq x \leq a, 0 \leq y \leq b \}$. We want to expand $f$ as
$$f(x,y) = \sum_{m \geq 1} \sum_{n \geq 1}a_{mn}\sin( \frac{m\pi x}{a}) \sin (\frac{n\pi y}{b}) \text{ (1)}$$
We make use of the identity:
$$\int_0^a \sin( \frac{m'\pi x}{a})\sin( \frac{m\pi x}{a}) \mathrm{d}x=\frac{a}{2}\delta_{mm'},$$
where $m,m' \in \mathbb{Z}$.
For the derivation we are assuming that all the conditions are satisfied to interchange the integral and sum and we get
$$\int_0^b \int_0^a f(x,y)\sin( \frac{m'\pi x}{a})\sin( \frac{n'\pi x}{b})\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y= \frac{ab}{4}a_{m'n'} \text{ (2)}$$
at this point assuming that $(1)$ is true to find out what the coefficients $a_{mn}$ have to be.

In the textbook once we get to line $(2)$ which I can do the derivation of, they then go on to say that this implies that
$$a_{mn}= \frac{4}{ab}\int_0^b \int_0^a f(x,y)\sin( \frac{m\pi x}{a})\sin( \frac{n\pi x}{b})\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y,$$
which is what I am having trouble with.

From what I understand $(2)$ is the inner product of $(f,\sin( \frac{m'\pi x}{a})\sin( \frac{n'\pi x}{b}))$ and then this somehow implies that the $a_{mn}$ must be as above.

I am missing something here =/

**EDIT** Bah, I am thinking it may just be simple algebra now that I look at it. -_-

I still don't know, any help is appreciated if it isn't too much to ask ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think in (1), (2) and last formula in the second sine you mean $y$ instead of $x$, e.i. it should be $\sin\left(\frac{n\pi y}{b}\right)$ but not $\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{b}\right)$. Under that assumption all your formulas would be correct but I will add some small explanation.

Having (1) you can multiply it by $\sin\left(\frac{m'\pi x}{a}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n'\pi x}{b}\right)$ and using integral identity will get the last equality.